# APR and large files

Tags: c++, c, apr

I want to use APR to mmap really large file, greater than 4Gb. At first I need to create file this big but I found that function `apr_file_seek` accepts parameter of type `apr_seek_where_t` that is just an alias for int. So it is possible to seek the first 4 gigs only. Is it possible to handle large files with APR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seek multiple times with APR_CUR.
Also note that an `int` on a 32-bit system allows you two seek *two* gibibytes forward, not four.

Also note that on a 32-bit system the `mmap` will most probably fail to map more than two to three gibibytes. (When the address space is limited by 32 bits the maximum address space is four gibibytes but the operating system has to reserve some of that address space to itself).